# PHP - a function that returns stuff that is echoed by other functions

Tags: php, function, variables

let's say I have a set of functions like,

- `article()` - outputs a article
- `menu()` - a menu

and so on...

sometimes I may need to only get the output of such functions, not print it to the screen. So instead of creating another set of functions that return the values like `get_article()`, `get_menu()` etc., could I make a single function that does this, using output buffering and `call_user_func`?

for eg.

```
function get($function_name){
  ob_start();
  call_user_func($function_name);
  return ob_get_contents();
}
```

the problem in my code is that I don't know how could I pass the `$function_name`'s arguments. The function might need any number of arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy...  Simply fetch the arguments using [`func_get_args`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)...

```
function get($function_name){
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    array_shift($arguments); // We need to remove the first arg ($function_name)
    ob_start();
    call_user_func_array($function_name, $arguments);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Usage:

```
function foo($arg1, $arg2) { echo $arg1 . ':' . $arg2; }

$bar = get('foo', 'test', 'ing'); // $bar = 'test:ing'
```

Note two things.

1. This is ignoring the `return` of the called function.
2. I changed the ending function to [`ob_get_clean()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) since it deletes the created buffer.  The code you had would make a new buffer for each call and not delete it (hence gradually slowing everything down as it needs to bubble all output up a large number of buffers)...

Answer (score 3):

Why not create an optional argument to signal whether to `return` or `echo` output something like this:

```
function article($output = false)
{
   // your code..........

   if ($output === true){
     echo $result;
   }
   else{
     return $result;
   }
}
```

Now if you want to echo something out of the same function, you should set `$output` to true when calling the function like this:

```
article(true);
```

But if you want to just ***return***  the result of the function, you can call it without specifying `$output`:

```
article();
```

Comment: yes, I thought of that too. But wouldn't something like my idea be more intuitive and elegant?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://ch.php.net/call_user_func_array), which would allow you to also pass an array of parameters. However it's probably better to make your `article()` function return a string and echo it only if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just modify `article()` and `menu()` to have a last optional parameter `$return` which is a boolean that defaults to `false` so when `$return` is `true` then you would return from the same function.

```
article($id, $return = false) 
{
  // ...
  if($return)
  {
    return $article;
  } else {
    echo $article;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could approach from the other way around, and write those functions in a way that they always return the values.

Then if you want to echo, you just say `echo article();`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.
You may like to look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).